# CodeIgniter Assets Not Found

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

Please help with CodeIgniter assets. I tried most of the solutions from StackOverflow (including the autoload utility helper), nothing works so far. Here's my setup below:

**Folder Path:**

[image: See Folder Path Below]

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.cs>
    RewriteBase /hnk_ci
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt) 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

When I view source code, it looks like this:

```
<link href="http://localhost/hnk_ci/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

But when click on the css link from source code, I get this error:

**The requested URL /hnk_ci/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css was not found on this server.**

Comment: i think you need to add css to this line so it can get to the folder inside assets:  RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)

Comment: Added css and still didn't work:    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|css|robots\.txt)

Comment: SOLVED! Folder structure was wrong - assets folder was inside application. I moved it outside and css is loading OK now. Thanks